# How to solve this quadratic bivariate recurrence relation?

Tags: recurrence-relations

Given the recurrence relation

$$\begin{aligned}
a_{n + 1} &= 2 a_n b_n\\
b_{n + 1} &= a_n^2 + b_n^2
\end{aligned}$$

with initial conditions

$$a_0 = a, \qquad b_0 = b$$

I am trying to come up with a formula for $a_n$ in terms of $a$ and $b$. I could come up with the following

$$\binom{a_{n + 1}}{b_{n + 1}} = \begin{pmatrix}b_n & a_n\\\ a_n & b_n\end{pmatrix} \binom{a_n}{b_n}$$

I'm not sure, how to proceed from here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not going to be a linear relation as there are products on the RHS.

Note from the two recursive relations that 
$$
b_{n+1} + a_{n+1} = (b_n + a_n)^2\\
b_{n+1} - a_{n+1} = (b_n - a_n)^2
$$

Hence 
$$
b_{n} + a_{n} = (b_0 + a_0)^{2^n}\\
b_{n} - a_{n} = (b_0 - a_0)^{2^n}
$$

and thus 
$$
b_{n} = \frac12(b_0 + a_0)^{2^n} + \frac12(b_0 - a_0)^{2^n} \\
a_{n} = \frac12(b_0 + a_0)^{2^n} - \frac12(b_0 - a_0)^{2^n}
$$

is the answer.

Comment: How can you get $2^n$ as the exponent?

Comment: @T.D. By the recursive equations, you always square the previous iteration - this gives $2^n$ in the exponent.